# How do I add a prompt to a Scan statement?

Tags: go, input, scanf, prompt

Question: How do I add a prompt to the beginning of a Scan statement in GoLang?

### Current Output:

```
Enter Phrase:
Hello World!
You typed: Hello world!
```

### Desired Output:

```
Enter Phrase: Hello world!
You typed: Hello world!
```

### My Code:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var phrase string
    fmt.Println("Enter Phrase: ")
    fmt.Scan(&phrase)
    fmt.Println("You typed: ", phrase)
}
```

P.S. I'm sorry for posting such an elementary question.
I have spent several hours researching, and I genuinely cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
Here is one solution in case other people have this problem:
use **fmt.Print** before your scan statement.

### Example:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var phrase string
    fmt.Print("Enter Phrase: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&phrase)
    fmt.Println("You typed: ", phrase)
}
```